# List append comes out wrong

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code as a problem.

```
list = [ [ ] ] * 5
print list
list[0].append(1)
print list
```

The first line prints `[[][][][][]]` which is what it should print 
but the second print gives

`[[1][1][1][1][1]]`

why does this happen? it is supposed to append only to the first list.

Comment: Not to answer your question, though you should avoid variable naming as built-in names...`list` is a built-in name

Comment: `list` is a Python built-in name , dont use it for a variable name

Comment: alright i just wanted to make an example.this is not the exact code.

Comment: why am i being downvoted?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer on the downvotes (the close vote was obviously correct), but I can guess -- as it was, the title for this question was much too vague to be useful; there are lots of ways for things to "come out wrong", whereas a more definite description (for instance, "list append affecting multiple lists") would have meant that readers could tell what you were asking about without needing to click through.

Comment: As an aside, a close cousin to this bug is what happens when one passes a list (or other mutable object) as a default parameter to a function -- every time the function is called without that parameter being overridden, a reference to that exact same object is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
list = [ [] ] * 5
```

...you're creating five **references** to the same inner list. Thus, appending to one of them appends to them all.

---

Consider instead:

```
l = [ [] for _ in range(5) ]
```

...which constructs a new list for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id) you can see that they refer to the same object.:

```
>>> l = [[]]*5
>>> for i in l:
    print id(i)


42277424
42277424
42277424
42277424
42277424
>>> 
>>> l[0].append(1)
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
>>> id(1)
32851648
>>> for lst in l:
    for item in lst:
        print 'item : {0}, list : {1}'.format(id(item), id(lst))


item : 32851648, list : 42277424
item : 32851648, list : 42277424
item : 32851648, list : 42277424
item : 32851648, list : 42277424
item : 32851648, list : 42277424
```

As you can see, `l` actually have five same references to one object, `[]`. So if you change anyone of them, you will see the same effect on the rest items